# create session and url redirection is creating 2 payment intent in stripe in react js

Tags: reactjs, node.js, stripes

When i try to create session and redirect to stripe payment and after success payment getting 2 payment_intent in which 1 is completed and 2nd is incomplete. I'm using React js in front and Node js in back.

When i try to create session and redirect to stripe payment and after success payment getting 2 payment_intent in which 1 is completed and 2nd is incomplete. I'm using React js in front and Node js in back and using stripe hosted page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.